# Bootstrap Tooltip not closing

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am using this bootstrap tutotria:  [Bootstrap tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tooltip_css&stacked=h)

and everything seems to be visualizing and working as intended. However when testing on touchscreen devices(Iphone 5s and Ipad2) it seems that the tooltip is not closing when you tap away. Do you have an idea how can I overcome this issue?

Cheers N

Comment: When you click the element tooltip stays, you can get rid of it by clicking away on screen. There is no hover over on touchscreen, touch = click. You must find the way to modify the code. Fade out on click or something.

Comment: @bigneo that is what I am trying to do however when I tap outside the tooltip the actual box is not closing and this is behavior that appears on real devices not in browser preview

Comment: So you are saying using the same code on browser phone view and on actual device you get two different results? That's odd.